# Dual boot Windows 7 UEFI Raid with Ubuntu 14.04 Grub2 Problem

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, raid, gpt

I used the intel Raid 0 to raid SSD #1 and #2 on raid 0 for video editing work, everything was good.I installed windows 7 64bit on an asus x79 deluxe motherboard on these raid 0 two ssds using UEFI+gpt, all went good.

I then installed 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a third non raid ssd # 3 with manual partitioning and I got gpt and UEFI on that and everything is almost all good. I can browse and see the windows raid windows partition but grub2 does not see list windows uefi.

In UEFI BIOS I can select UEFI Windows boot manager or UEFI Ubuntu boot manager and each will boot respectively from their own boot manager.  However I want to add the UEFI Windows boot manger to grub2 so I can select the OS from GRUB2 and not have to go into bios to choose OS.

How can I do this?  I tried boot repair but it seems to screw things up to the point of reinstall. I wonder is there is a way to manually add the windows boot loader to grub2 and daisy chain UEFI Windows boot manager?

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it should probably be working, although your use of RAID on Windows might have thrown a monkey wrench into it. I can think of a number of possible solutions. The first is to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and create an entry resembling the following:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

You may need to change `(hd0,gpt1)` to identify the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) where the Windows boot loader is stored. With this done, type `sudo update-grub` to add the manual entry to GRUB.

A second option is to run [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which often does a better job of identifying strange GRUB setups than do the stock Ubuntu GRUB scripts. The danger is that Boot Repair occasionally makes matters worse, particularly with exotic setups. If you run Boot Repair, be sure to save the URL that it gives you. If it doesn't work, you can post that URL back here to give us more detailed information about your setup.

Finally, you could try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If you do this, I recommend you start with the USB flash drive or CD-R version; you can try these without making changes to your disk setup or boot loader options list, so the risk factor is very low. If you can boot both Ubuntu and Windows from the rEFInd external medium, install the raw Debian package or PPA in Ubuntu.

You can try these options in any order you like.

Comment: The first option worked great exactly as is.  Thank you very very much.

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the machine which has Windows 7 installed on two raid solid-state drives that are formatted with gpt and use UEFI. Ubuntu is actually installed on the third non-raid solid-state drive. The following steps describe the situation. I installed it on a motherboard which is the Asus X79 Deluxe. There are two more raid drives, each consisting of two regular hard drives that are formatted under Windows to be used for storage of data.

The first step is to turn off fast boot and enable raid controller to be entered using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> command by adjusting the UEFI setting to force display and turn off fast boot as well as secure boot. Then I entered their Intel raid BIOS and also used -<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for the other controller to make my RAID partitions. Then used Windows 7 DVD installed it onto the RAID partition. Everything under Windows works well after install.

In the second step I booted the Ubuntu 14.04 live CD using UEFI boot and then once booted into the CD I did the install of / and swap. I also made first partition of the Windows as the boot loader destination, that is why there is an extra partition in the first set. The installation went fine but then on reboot grub2 does not show up and the only way to boot into the two operating systems is by selecting where to boot from in the UEFI bios. I then went and installed boot-repair which must be installed on the newly installed Ubuntu system, with the option of secure boot turned off and follow the instructions. I tried using the boot-repair cd and installing it on the live CD ubuntu boot and the boot-repair launches but wants to convert everything to MBR instead this enabled me to get the Grub2 to show up without the capability to select Windows when booting from the Linux solid-state drive.

I finally added option one from above and it allowed me to put the Windows boot manager into the grub2 so now everything works as it should.

It took quite a few reinstalls and messing about to finally get to that stage. But in the end I have a system exactly the way I need it to be.